# Generate a excel using java and create a macro in the excel

Tags: java, excel, vba, outlook, apache-poi

I have a java code that takes data from MongoDB and later creates an excel(.xls) containing this data using Apache POI but in a formatted manner.

My final requirement is to mail the last worksheet inside the excel sheet to a set of mail ID's. I cannot use the Java mail API to do that since the SMTP details of the mailbox will not be provided to me.
As of now I am planning to create a macro inside the generated excel to send the data. The macro I have created to send mail is:

```vb
Sub Send_Selection_Or_ActiveSheet_with_MailEnvelope()
'Working in Excel 2002-2016
    Dim Sendrng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Selection

    'Create the mail and send it
    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "This is a test mail."

            With .Item
                .To = "iamnithinprakash@gmail.com"
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .Send
            End With

        End With
    End With

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

But I don't know how to create this macro using java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asks how to create Excel sheet using the Apache POI library that include macros. Unfortunately: that is not possible.

Quoting the POI [limitations](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html):

> Macros can not be created. The are currently no plans to support macros.

Luckily, it continues:

> However, reading and re-writing files containing macros will safely preserve the macros.

So, what *could* work out:

- you create an *empty* Excel sheet "manually", with Excel, that includes your macro
- you use POI to **add** the data to such an existing sheet
- you save that "together" into a new sheet

(or some variation of that, like creating that empty template, copy that, and open/update one of the copies)

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. It's a good idea but I can't create an excel file manually. This is part of a webservice and the excel sheet is generated depending on the inputs provided.

Comment: So it seems if I need to add the macro into excel sheet then I would have to create excel using plugin other than poi.

Comment: @NitKrish In what format are you creating the Excel file? The old .xls format or the newer .xlsx format? You wrote *xls* but I want it confirmed

Comment: @GhostCat yes I am creating an .xls file.

Comment: I think your idea is much better. I have isolated this particular functionality and I am adding an excel containing no data but only the macro. I'll try using some JAVA-to-COM bridge to invoke the macro.

Comment: @GhostCat I been trying to implement this. I have kept an excel sheet which acts as the template but when data is written into it excel losses the macro. Thus I am not able to run the macro. Do you know how to write data without losing the macro.

Comment: @NitKrish Unfortunately, no. My suggestion would be to then directly talk to the Apache POI team, for example on their user forum: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/POI-User-f2280730.html